# How could i condense 3 mysql queries; using AVG and COUNT

Tags: mysql, join, pdo

Could these queries be condensed into 2, or even better 1 query?

**Query 1**

```
$stmt = $conn->
prepare("
    SELECT providers.Provider_ID, providers.Description, reviews.Date, reviews.F_Name, reviews.S_Name, reviews.Website, reviews.Rating, reviews.Message, reviews.Email_Address
    FROM providers
    INNER JOIN reviews ON reviews.Provider=providers.Provider_ID    
    WHERE providers.Provider_ID LIKE CONCAT('%',:provider,'%') LIMIT $set_limit 
");
$stmt->bindParam(':provider', $provider, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Query 2**

```
$stmt = $conn->
prepare("
    SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as AVG_Rating
    FROM reviews
    WHERE Provider LIKE CONCAT('%',:provider,'%') 
");
$stmt->bindParam(':provider', $provider, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$get_average = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

**Query 3**

```
$stmt = $conn->
prepare("
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM reviews
    WHERE Provider LIKE CONCAT('%',:provider,'%') 
");
$stmt->bindParam(':provider', $provider, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$total_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: It is easy to do with one query the last two.

Comment: Doh! You're right. Thanks alot, i didn't try it because in my head it seemed illogical. It couldn't be condensed into one those could it, i was wondering about sub-queries. But then again, i read that two queries is often faster than a query + sub-query. :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are bringing together results at different levels of granularity.  One is at the provider level and the other at the review level.  So, you want reviews with summary information.  You can get this by joining in the aggregated results:

```
SELECT p.Provider_ID, p.Description, r.Date, r.F_Name, r.S_Name,
       r.Website, r.Rating, r.Message, r.Email_Address,
       tsum.AVG_Rating, tsum.cnt
FROM providers p INNER JOIN
     reviews r
     ON r.Provider = p.Provider_ID CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT Provider, ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as AVG_Rating, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM reviews
      WHERE Provider LIKE CONCAT('%',:provider,'%')
     ) tsum
WHERE p.Provider_ID LIKE CONCAT('%',:provider,'%')
LIMIT $set_limit
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks man! I see there are 3 INNER JOINS, would this have a higher overhead than just two queries(If i grouped the last two).

Comment: Think you need a GROUP BY clause in the sub query

Comment: Also, aren't you missing `AS`s

Comment: @Kickstart . . . I agree that a `group by` is reasonable.  However, the original query creates one row for the summaries, even when multiple providers might match the `where` clause.  I changed the join to a `cross join` to more clearly match the behavior of the query in the original posting.

Comment: @JackWilliams . . . I only use `as` for column aliases.  The table alias is there.

Comment: Accepted your answer as it was the most thorough, an explanation of CROSS JOIN and why it's needed would've be useful though, but i digress. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Query 2 and Query 3 can easily be combined into a single query:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as AVG_Rating
     , COUNT(*) AS count_
FROM reviews
WHERE Provider LIKE CONCAT('%',:provider,'%')
```

But you won't be able to use `fetchColumn()`, you'd need to fetch the row and access each column.

This query (like Query 2 and Query 3) returns a single row. Query 1 has the potential to return 0, 1 or more rows, so combining that query is a bit more problematic. It would be possible to return the `AVG_Rating` and `count_` on every row, but your code to handle that resultset would be a little less straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! @Hamlet Hakobyan had made the same point, i'll definitely do that at a minimum.